# Quickly determine access to ntp server

Tags: c++, ntp

I'm trying to create a method that determines access to the ntp server. I made a simple method, but if there is no connection, then it waits a long time for an answer - 5 seconds. I check 5 servers like this, for example - **time.nist.gov**. We have to wait a very long time.
Question: is there an easy way to check to avoid waiting so long, about 1-2 seconds?

```
bool is_connection(char* url)
{
    // time.nist.gov
    return gethostbyname(url) != NULL;
}
```

Comment: `gethostbyname` is obsolete, use `getaddrinfo`. You are looking for adns.

Comment: There is no way to pass a timeout to the `getaddrinfo` system call

Comment: `gethostbyname` is not checking access to NTP servers. It just resolves their IP addresses. You can store the IP address once resolved by `gethostbyname` and do proper checking in `is_connection`.

Comment: `gethostbyname` is also waiting for a response

Answer (score 0):

First, you should do all these checks in separated threads and join them to get the whole results in a single request.

Second, NTP uses UDP, so you can't check if the port (123 for NTP) is open or not, since UDP isn't a connected protocol - i.e. you don't have delivery results unless the server sends back another datagram to acknowledge your datagram. With TCP, you can "ping" a port to check if it's open, but not in UDP. You'll need to dive into RFC 1305 in order to be able to check that.
Resolving the name won't help you to check if it's a valid and working NTP server.

Anyway, your problem can be easily solved, but the solution is most likely dependent of your operating system (type, version, ...), your compiler (type, version, C++ standard used, ...), and the allowed C++ frameworks for your case (open bar, restricted, portable or not, ...).

I highly doubt that an EFFICIENT solution in pure portable C++ exists, in particular if you're stuck with old C++ standards. An efficient solution is more likely totally platform-dependent.
You should precise your working environment in order to get a more precise solution.